# Why does ./sbin/start-master.sh give "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main"?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm new to spark.
I'm installing spark-1.5.2-bin-without-hadoop.tgz on single node.
I have done with my configuration.

When I'm going to start my master node by using the following command its showing me the error.Please Help me.

```
Command : ./sbin/start-master.sh 
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to   /usr/local/spark/sbin/../logs/spark-jalaj-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-CIPL367.out
failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master:
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
full log in /usr/local/spark/sbin/../logs/spark-jalaj-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-CIPL367.out
```

Comment: So what's your configuration?

Comment: Can you post the output of log file?

Comment: Start over using `sh -x ./sbin/start-master.sh`. It's gonna tell us about incorrect CLASSPATH, but can't figure it out why now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your comments.

I have reinstalled spark 1.5.2 and it works for me.
Earlier the problem was with the spark-1.5.2.tar file.
So I downloaded the fresh tar file of spark 1.5.2 and reinstall spark and now it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've found on a couple rare occasions something happens to the JAR file and it gets corrupted; you can test it via `unzip -l ./spark/lib/spark-assembly-*` and if you get an error message you'll just need to replace the JAR with a non-corrupted version. (If you instead see a list of files then that JAR file is okay, at least.)